# Mobile Number Validation Regex

Tags: jquery, regex, validation

I am looking for a Regex Validation for the Mobile number validation specifically for Zimbabwe.I already using one `^263[0-9]{9}$` and is working fine now. But now I need to add the mobile prefix along.The mobile prefixes should be one of these (71,73,74,77,78) else it should be considered as invalid

Totally 12 numbers with the dialing code, mobile prefix and number eg:263711321345. How to check for these mobile prefixes in regex validation?

Comment: ^263[7][13478][0-9]{7}$  --> at last my regex look like this now.Thanks for the help guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the answer would be instead:

```
^2637[13478][0-9]{7}$
```

Also, the example phone number given doesn't have 12 digits, so it wouldn't match.

Comment: Thanks.Yes I noticed the given number is only 11 digit.I updated it.

Answer (score 3):

This

```
(\+263|0)7[7-8|1|3][0-9]{7}$
```

is a minor improvement on Tinashe`s answer tested [here](https://regex101.com/r/rs7Ekc/1)

It checks all the 3 networks Telecel ,Netone and Econet and also takes either +263 or 0 as the prefix

Comment: Probably review the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) which contains notes around many common beginner errors, such as your incorrect use of `|` inside character classes.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer to validate with respect to each mobile operator you can use the following

```
let re = /2637[7-8][0-9]{7}$/
//for econet numbers

let re = /26371[0-9]{7}$/
//for netone numbers

let re = /26373[0-9]{7}$/
//for telecel numbers


let re = /2637[7-8|1|3][0-9]{7}$
//universal for the three major operators
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
^[7][13478]263[0-9]{9}$
```

Check [Here](https://regex101.com/r/hbdOGH/1)

Comment: Thanks.By this, we are having the prefix before the dialing code '78263123456987' but I need it after the dialing code 263.So can I change the place of it?Does it still work in that case?

Comment: Thanks for the Regex I changed the position and the total numbers and now I am getting correctly.It is looking like this now  ^263[7][13478][0-7]{7}$

Answer (score -2):

```
/^[+2637|07][7-8|1|3][0-9]{7}$/
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [answer] and [edit] your answer to contain an explanation as to why this code would actually solve the problem at hand. Always remember that you're not only solving the problem, but are also educating the OP and any future readers of this post.

Comment: Probably also review the [Stack Overflow `regex` tag info page](/tags/regex/info) which contains notes around many common beginner errors, such as your incorrect use of character classes and `|` inside character classes.

Comment: Please add some explanation for your code rather than posting code only. Additional explanation will be more helpful.